# SQL Logic for a gap

Tags: sql, logic

```
0   0   0   0   1   0   1
0   0   0   1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I am trying to find a logic where I check each column and compare to flag where there is a 0 between two ones or there are two one's and a zero and one again. I want to write a SQL Query for the same.

Comment: This is really unclear.  Add your desired output and whatever query you've attempted.  And include the column names in your table(?)

Comment: Looks like a huge CASE?

Comment: whats your database...basically you want to develop a range...you can usually get a sequence of row numbers using the system catalog tables

Answer (score 1):

There's not a ton to go by in this question, but given the basic requirement of looking for `101` gaps in columns like you provided above, you could concatenate the values together and look for literally the string `'101'`. It's not that performant, but it works:

```
WITH yourData(one,two,three,four,five, six) AS (
    select 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 union 
    select 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 union
    select 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 union
    select 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 
),
concatenated(concatenatedValue) as (
    SELECT
        CAST(one as varchar)+CAST(two as varchar)+CAST(three as varchar)+CAST(four as varchar)+CAST(five as varchar)+CAST(six as varchar)
    FROM yourData
)
select 
    concatenatedValue 
from 
    concatenated
where 
    concatenatedValue like '%101%'
```

The above returns the following rows:

```
000101
001101
```

Keep in mind that `yourData` is just a rough guess at your data, and should be replaced with your own table.

Comment: Although the idea appears correct, I could not upvote this answer for several reasons.  First, it is explicitly for SQL Server, without noting that at all.  More importantly, it uses `varchar` without a length parameter, which is very bad form.  Third, it uses `union` where `union all` -- or better yet, `values` -- is more appropriate.